# Preventing Colors of Graphics from Blending

Tags: graphics, color

I am displaying multiple Disks that overlap and many of the Disks are different colors. Currently, the regions in which the Disks overlap are a color that is a mixture of the two Disks. I would like for that region to only be the color of the later Disk in the list. Is there a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the default behavior:

```
col[i_] := ColorData[15][RandomInteger[{0, 10}]]
Graphics@Table[{EdgeForm[Black], col[i], Disk[{i, 0}, 1]}, {i, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, perhaps I have some other issues within my code.

Comment: @dleggas Check for `Opacity[]` options in there